# Using reusable components with ReactJs and Flux with multiple stores

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux

In my company, we started our first project with ReactJs. Because in the end this might grow into a large system, we decided to use Flux to keep things organized. Although there are quite some examples, they mostly are not based on usage in a complex system.

One of the things that we would like to realize is a UI that makes use of widget-like components. For example, we have a component that displays information of a customer. This widget will be used on a tab-page with info of an invoice, but also on another tab-page with a customer card in the same browser window. And there will be some other components in which this widget will be used.

So I have a React component that should listen to a change event of a store. However this component itself does not know what store to listen to, because I can have an invoice store, but also another store that has customer info that should be displayed.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26793023/flux-react-complex-reusable-component) question that gives some info on how to create a re-usable component, but it does not give some tips on how to use a component with multiple stores.

One thing that I consider is to pass the store to be used as a parameter into the re-usable component. Would this be a wise thing to do?

Thanks in advance for your reactions!

Comment: You should keep state in just one place in parent component container and pass props down to each component and manage change listeners in  parent container component only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to go would be to handle all the data retrieval logic in a parent component. In that model, your `CustomerCard` component doesn't need to know how to retrieve its data, but expect it to be passed as props instead. This is a win for reusability since your `CustomerCard` component isn't tied to a specific data retrieval process anymore.

In your case, you could create one container component per store, and each one of them would return a `<CustomerCard customerInfo={...} />` element in their `render()` method.

Comment: Ok. I will go for this approach. Together with thge remark of @Ajay Beniwal this makes sense to me. Thanks for your reaction.